# Java: Allow spaces and punctuation in strings

Tags: java, string

I am working on an assignment and came across something interesting. I am trying to allow the user to input a sentence, such as "Computer Programming is fun!" and then for it to use my custom conversion to make it into numbers using ASCII. I noticed that it only converts the first word from the sentence the user gives. When decoding, it also only decodes the first word. Below is my work:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project7{
  public static String decode(String finalDecode){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many characters long is your encoded message?");
    int characters = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your encoded message on a single line:");
    String decodeMessage = "";
    int ascii = input.nextInt();
    char ch = (char)ascii;
    decodeMessage = decodeMessage + Character.toString(ch);
    for(int i = 1; i < characters;i++){
      int val = input.nextInt();
      ch = (char)(ascii + val);
      decodeMessage = decodeMessage + Character.toString(ch);
      ascii = ascii+val;
    }
    System.out.print("Your decoded message is: " + decodeMessage);
    return finalDecode;
  }
  public static int encode(int[] encodeArray){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence to encode:");
    String encode = input.next().toUpperCase();
    encodeArray = new int[encode.length()];
    int ascii = encode.charAt(0);
    encodeArray[0] = ascii; 
    System.out.println("Encoded sentence is:");
    System.out.print(ascii + " ");
    for (int i = 1; i < encode.length(); i++) {
      ascii = encode.charAt(i - 1);
      encodeArray[i] = encode.charAt(i) - ascii;
      System.out.print(encode.charAt(i) - ascii + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    return encodeArray.length;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String finalDecode = " ";
    int choice = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
      System.out.println("Enter 1 to encode, 2 to decode, 0 to quit:");
      choice = input.nextInt();
      if(choice == 1){
        int[] array = null;
        encode(array);
      }else if(choice == 2){
        String decode = "";
        decode(decode);
        System.out.println(finalDecode);
      }else{
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        break;
      }
    }while(true);
  } 
}
```

Comment: so, read it as a String

Comment: Adding line breaks in your code will make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Check the third line in your encode method.

```
String encode = input.next().toUpperCase();
```

Scanner.next() takes only one word. Change it to

```
String encode = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
```

which will read the whole line. and your programm works.

This is because Scanner.next() is used to iterate throu parts of a String using a delimiter to separate. And the default delimiter is the whitespace " ".
see this example:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("Computer Programming is fun!");
while(s.hasNext())
    System.out.println(s.next());
```

it prints every word of the sentence in a new line.

Now instead of using nextLine() in your encode method you could also set Newline as delimiter and stay with next().

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.useDelimiter("\n");
```